# Creating a MongoDB schema based on components from schema.org

Tags: mongodb, database-schema, json-ld

I'm trying to create a new MongoDB database schema for a CRM application by leveraging [schema.org](https://schema.org/)'s schemas. It's not very clear to my how to put things together as I'm quite new to MongoDB and never used schema.org before. I started by creating Mongo schemas for Person, PostalAddress, Country, Place, Organization and bellow you can find my current Mongo schema for [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization):

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const organizationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  address: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: "PostalAddress"
  },
  award: String,
  founder: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: "Person"
  },
  legalName: String,
  logo: String,
  memberOf: {
    type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    ref: "Organization"
  },
  numberOfEmployees: Number,
  slogan: String
})

export const Organization = mongoose.model("organization", organizationSchema)
```

There are three things I need to find out:

1. Am I doing this the right way?
2. Since Organization is a [Thing](https://schema.org/Thing), do I need to put the properties from Thing in the same schema?
3. Let's say I need to add the available bank accounts for this organization. The apropiate schema would be BankAccount, but how do I tie this to my Organization given the fact that the "chain" for BankAccount is Thing > Intangible > Service > FinancialProduct > BankAccount?